# pouchDb last sync requests taking too long to respond

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

I've made an application in ionic V1 using pouchDb and couchDb databases. Everything was working fine, except for some loading problem.
When I initially start the application, pouchDb tries to fetch changes from couchDb, but the last sync request is taking too long to finish, sometimes more than 10 minutes or so.
Due to this, all operations on pouchDb are also taking too much time.

```
couchDb version is 1.6.1
pouchDb version is 6.1.1
```

[image: last pouchDb sync request]
Is this a problem with pouchDb/couchDb? Did anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: Are you syncing a lot of data? Have you tried splitting up your data in smaller parts?

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of data to sync. But how can I split it into smaller parts?